# PHP Maths Logic

Tags: php, math

I am trying to set a variable based on some maths logic (to wrap specific html around elements).

I worked half the problem, to hit 0, 3, 6, 9, 12

```
if(($i % 3) == 0) { // blah }
```

Now I need to hit the following numbers, 2, 5, 8, 11, 14, etc

What possible maths operation could I do to hit this sequence?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
if($i % 3 == 1)
if($i % 3 == 2)
```

Modulo returns the remainder, so when you match the 0, you get the 3rd, 6th, 9th, etc, because 0 is left in the division.

So just check for when 1 remains and 2 remains.

Comment: lol, as i saw the sequence after posting, i thought add one to $i and run the same test. this is even better though. thanks very much, been thinking too long on that one.

Comment: once you get comfortable with all the things modulo can do, you'll become a better programmer. newbies tend to discard it as "something fancy", while it is indeed an essential operator. also: you don't need parens around the expression.

Answer (score 3):

Along with Tor Valamo's answer you can notice the pattern of `(3 * $i) - 1`

```
(3*1)-1 = 2
(3*2)-1 = 5
(3*3)-1 = 8
   ...
```

Answer (score 2):

if((($i-2) % 3) == 0) { // blah }